# randomly select from dropdown list python

Tags: python, selenium

I am new in python selenium. I do not have any idea to do this. Please help. I appreciated.

```
<select name="country" id="country" class="" title="Country" data-validate="{'validate-select':true}" aria-required="true" xpath="1">
<option value=""> </option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AD">Andorra</option>
<option value="AO">Angola</option>
<option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
<option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
<option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
```

I made research and i am extracting all country names but i need select randomly 1 country from extraction. 
here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://account.magento.com/customer/account/create/")


element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='country']")
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in all_options:
    print(option.text)
```

[Here is picture you can see. I want to select randomly 1 country from dropdown list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSCVD.jpg)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import random  

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://account.magento.com/customer/account/create/")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='country']")
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

random_country = random.choice(all_options)
print (random_country)
```

Comment: C:\DEV\practice\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/DEV/practice/test9.py
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8b9c314d05a2b55048b3ec597f08c229", element="2eb32b77-51a0-40be-b5fb-412fa46437ae")>

Process finished with exit code 0================This is the result===========  it is not i expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 
country  = [ "India", "China", "South Africa", "UAE", "UK", "Italy"] // Add your country here
print(random.choice(country))
```

Use  `random.choice()` for random selection.