# Is there any way to add number in front of the element

Tags: python, selenium

## MY CODE

```
    sidebar = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('menusubnav')
    elementList = sidebar.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    for i in range(len(elementList)):
       element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('menusubnav').find_elements_by_tag_name("li")[i]
       print(enumerate, element.text)
```

===================================RESULT=========================

```
   C:\DEV\practice\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/DEV/practice/test_case.py
   test_guru (__main__.LoginGuruTest) ... 
   <class 'enumerate'> Manager
   <class 'enumerate'> New Customer
   <class 'enumerate'> Edit Customer
   <class 'enumerate'> Delete Customer
   <class 'enumerate'> New Account
   <class 'enumerate'> Edit Account
   <class 'enumerate'> Delete Account
   <class 'enumerate'> Deposit
   <class 'enumerate'> Withdrawal
   <class 'enumerate'> Fund Transfer
   <class 'enumerate'> Change Password
   <class 'enumerate'> Balance Enquiry
   <class 'enumerate'> Mini Statement
   <class 'enumerate'> Customised Statement
   <class 'enumerate'> Log out
   ===  Alert shows following message:  ====
   ===========================================
   ||   You Have Succesfully Logged Out!!   ||
   ===========================================
   ok
   test_screenshot_logout (__main__.LoginGuruTest) ... ok

   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 2 tests in 28.417s

   OK

   Process finished with exit code 0
```

========================================================================

I WANT THIS ONE   ---- NUMBERING THE RESULT OF THE PAGE ELEMENTS

======================================================================

```
     1. Manager
     2. New Customer
     3. Edit Customer
     4. Delete Customer
     5. New Account
     6. Edit Account
     7. Delete Account
     8. Deposit
     9. Withdrawal
     10. Fund Transfer
     11. Change Password
     12. Balance Enquiry
     13. Mini Statement
     14. Customised Statement
     15. Log out
```

==========================================================================

Thank you

Comment: you want the numbering for only first 4 ?

Comment: no all it is example only 4 i want all elements numbering

Comment: `print(f"{i}. {element.text}")` shall get what you want.

Comment: Thank you.  Abbas. good job.

Comment: Abbas    I had another question can you help with that also. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60683482/9441796      Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should suffice:

```
for i, element in enumerate(elementList):
       print(i+1, element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dear, Please try to print this code and will be working**

```
print(str(i + 1) +'.' +element.text)
```